# localStorage only saves first member of array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, local-storage

---

Every time I want to get the array from `localStorage` it only gets me the last value.I think it handles the array as a object. How do I fix this?

```
function saveData() {


    if ($("#forma").valid() == true) {

        var Name = document.getElementById("username").value;
        var Year = document.getElementById("godinaupisa").value;
        var Index1 = document.getElementById("brindeksa").value;
        console.log(Name);
        var EMial = document.getElementById("email").value;
        var OBJ = { NAME: "JOHN DOE", YEAR: "18", INDEX1: "1", EMAIL: "@" };


        OBJ.NAME = Ime1;
        OBJ.YEAR = Year;
        OBJ.INDEX1 = Index1;
        OBJ.EMAIL = EMial;

        var arrayOBJ = [];
        arrayOBJ.push(OBJ);

        localStorage.setItem("ARRAY", JSON.stringify(arrayOBJ));
        alert("saved");

        $("#forma").resetForm;

    };
}
```

Comment: The ending bracket is missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, you're calling `setItem` which will just set it to whatever you pass it. I think what you want to go is read the current value, append to that and set the new value to be that.

```
var data = localStorage.getItem("ARRAY");
data = JSON.parse(data);
data.push(OBJ);
localStorage.setItem("ARRAY", data);
```

Comment: I did as you said but every time I call it back up into a new var that is array and try to access anything but the first spot t gives me a error

Comment: @King23 throw your code into a (codepen)[www.codepen.io] so I can see what you're doing. Just telling me you're getting an error doesn't really give me much to go on.

Comment: I can, but sadly  most of it isn't in English I doubt you could understand it.
All I want to store several objects as one array that I can add object later as I want and when I call it from local that I get the whole array

Comment: I don't know what getting you to put your code into a codepen has to do with your English skills haha

Code is code, doesn't matter what language it's in.

Comment: I was referring to the html and JavaScript names for the variables as well as the interface, but as you wish (you will regret asking)[https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OgQeqL]

Comment: You didn't implement what I suggested and or you did it wrong. You're still using an empty array.

Comment: And in the place where you did change to using `getItem` first, you weren't actually calling `setItem`

Comment: So I should use the same array at start throughout the entire process?

Comment: Depends on what you're trying to do. If you're adding stuff to an array and you want it all to be saved, yes.

Comment: I made it work using only 1 global array. Will the content of the array still be there if I close the site and start a new session?

Answer (score 1):

Because you create the arrayOBJ array each time you try to save, you're only ever going to have one item inside of it. And when you save it to localstorage you're just writing over anything that was already there. Instead try defining arrayOBJ outside your save function as a global variable.
Alternatively you can use `localStorage.getItem` and `JSON.parse` to get the current array that's in localStorage before pushing to it.